# C# - How instantiate a class from database at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, mapping

Scenario: I have the following table in a SQL Server database that is used by different modules of the entire system (so it must remain as it is and where it is):

[image: SQL Table]

| id | field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | val2 |
| 2 | val2 | val3 |
| 3 | val4 | val5 |

I'm developing a module of the system written in C# and .NET framework (.NET Core 3.1) where I need the data in the table.

To solve this kind of problem, I usually "replicate" the table on my code with a static class:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static class Element1
    {
        public const int id = 1;
        public const string field1 = "val1";
        public const string field2 = "val2";
    }

    public static class Element2
    {
        public const int id = 2;
        public const string field1 = "val2";
        public const string field2 = "val3";
    }
}
```

So I can access the data like that:

```
Constants.Element1.id;
```

Obviously, this way is very raw and it needs every data in the table to be replicated in the code.

My idea is to search for something that loads the table from the database at runtime and populates the class in C#. Is it a good idea? Or maybe there is a more robust and elegant way to do that?

Comment: Use [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) or (more lightweight) [dapper.net](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper)

Comment: I have already seen a similar question about this table and image by another account but I do not really remember the subject ...

Comment: @OlivierRogier sorry first times I'm using StackOverflow. Previous question was not clear and had been closed. So I tried to clarify the scenario and posted a new one. I'm sorry if I did something wrong.